# Too Many Arguments for IF, And, Or Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am in need of some help, been getting killed with this for weeks now. This statement is used to determine if a line item is still open, closed or requires re-submittal. It comes as "False" or Too Many Arguments. Can someone review and possibly tell me where my mistake is? thank you so much.

```
=IF(AND(G231="FIO",N231>0),"C"," "),=IF(OR(G231="DA",G231="CR",G231="DA/CR"),IF(AND(N231>0,P231=0),"O",IF(AND(N231>0,P231>0),IF(OR(O231="A",O231="AN",O231="B"),"C",IF(OR(O231="C",O231="E",O231="G",O321="X"),"R"," "),=IF(OR(G231="GA",G231="DA/GA"),IF(AND(N231>0,T231=0),"O",IF(AND(N231>0,T231>0),IF(OR(S231="A",S231="AN",S231="B"),"C",IF(OR(S231="C",S231="E",S231="G",S321="X"),"R"," ")))))
```

Comment: 3 formulas in the same cell?

Answer (score 2):

Start by removing the `=` from wherever it's after a comma and before the word `IF`.

This at the beginning is a complete formula:

```
=IF(AND(G231="FIO",N231>0),"C"," ")
```

It's saying "IF G231 is FIO and N231 is greater than 0, then return C otherwise return a space".

You can't then follow that formula with `,=IF` in the same formula.

```
...),=IF...
```

Wherever you have that kind of thing, you need to remove it and rethink from scratch.

Try writing it out in plain language.

- If G231 is FIO and N231 is greater than zero, return a C, otherwise:
- IF G231 is either DA, CR or DA/CR, then:
- IF N231 is greater than zero AND P231 is 0, then return a zero, otherwise:
- IF(..." etc

If you write out what you're doing, you may find it's easier to write the formula in the end.

Since it's not completely clear what you're trying to achieve, I'm afraid I can't offer much more advice than the above and this:

If your version of Excel supports the IFS function, you will find it's much easier to use than lots of nested IF functions.

[Microsoft Support - IFS Function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ifs-function-36329a26-37b2-467c-972b-4a39bd951d45)

Answer (score 1):

Like Flex said in his answer, there's a pretty deep logic flaw in the formula, that violates the very nature of an excel function.  I want to build upon his answer and provide some insight into how to build a complex set of conditions, that can be used not just for this problem but for others.  And then I'll use some of those tips to illustrate problems with your formula along the way.

**1.  If available in your version of excel, use the LET function to create more readable complex functions**

Combining the LET function with using Alt-Enter to create multi-line formulas dramatically simplifies complexity.  Your original function as-is using the LET function becomes:

```
=LET(
condA, AND(G231="FIO",N231>0),
condB, OR(G231="DA",G231="CR",G231="DA/CR"),
condC, AND(N231>0,P231=0),
condD, AND(N231>0,P231>0),
condE, OR(O231="A",O231="AN",O231="B"),
condF, OR(O231="C",O231="E",O231="G",O321="X"),
condG, OR(G231="GA",G231="DA/GA"),
condH, AND(N231>0,T231=0),
condI, AND(N231>0,T231>0),
condJ, OR(S231="A",S231="AN",S231="B"),
condK, OR(S231="C",S231="E",S231="G",S321="X"),
IF(condA,"C"," "),
=IF(condB,IF(condC,"O",IF(condD,IF(condE,"C",IF(condF,"R"," "),
=IF(condG,IF(condH,"O",IF(condI,IF(condJ,"C",IF(condK,"R"," "))))
)
```

This is still not a valid formula, but we have separated the complexity of the conditions from the logic in a way that makes it much easier to focus on our IF statements.  Now it's easier to see where you went wrong.

**2. You actually have three unrelated formulas run together in one cell, and that won't work**

You actually have 3 distinct IF statements glued together in a cell.  One single IF followed by two sets of IFs nested 3 deep.  Here they are in my simplified format:

```
=IF(condA,"C"," "),
=IF(condB,IF(condC,"O",IF(condD,IF(condE,"C",IF(condF,"R"," "),
=IF(condG,IF(condH,"O",IF(condI,IF(condJ,"C",IF(condK,"R"," "))))
```

**3. So how do we build complex conditions?**

Another thing that our simplified format reveals more easily is that all these IFs only ever had 4 possible outcomes:  C, O, R, and SPACE.  As a general rule (there are exceptions) let's try to write our conditions in such a way that there is one condition, or one IF, per outcome.  So start with the end in mind by writing your first pass in plain language as:

```
This cell should contain C when: *list conditions*
This cell should contain O when: *list conditions*
This cell should contain R when: *list conditions*
This cell should contain " " when: *list conditions*
0therwise, it should contain *whatever*
```

So you can use all your nested ANDs and ORs to express the listed conditions as FOUR (plus one default if there's no match, if needed) condition formulas:

```
condC = blah blah blah
condO = blah blah blah
condR = blah blah blah
condSpace = blah blah blah
otherwise = blah
```

Now these conditions are easy to enter into a LET-simplified nested IF, and let's assume if there's no match you wanted a null:

```
LET(
condC, blah blah blah,
condO, blah blah blah,
condR, blah blah blah,
condSpace, blah blah blah,
IF(condC, "C", IF(condO, "O", IF(condR, "R", IF(condSpace, " ", ""))))
)
```

**4. And finally, if your version supports it, create a simpler IF-THEN-ELSEIF logic structure using IFS instead of IF:**

```
IFS(condC, "C", condO, "O", condR, "R", condSpace, " ", TRUE, "")
```

IFS arguments are in the form: condition, result, condition, result, etc.  The IF function exits with the result the first time a TRUE condition is encountered, from left to right and then continues to the next condition/result only if not.   It will only move on to check "condO" if "condC" wasn't met.  We create a default "if all else failed" answer by simply making the last condition TRUE and giving a result.  If a "not found" result is not needed, then the formula can be simplified to:

```
IFS(condC, "C", condO, "O", condR, "R", condSpace, " ")
```

And remember, I am assuming that this IFS function goes inside a LET function that first defines the four conditions.

Hope this helps.  I wanted to create a more complete answer that might be useful for you, and for future searchers who may be linked to this answer by a "see also:"

Comment: Nice one. Parameterize those cell references in that LET and wrap it in a nice easy lambda. Lambda for everything.